# Make UILabel appear on top of UIImageView in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uistoryboard

I want to make the a label appear over an image view. But when I place the label over it it disappears. Whats the best way around this?

I have a couple of labels over my image view. When I build and run it the labels appear fine. But on the storyboard when I place ui items such as a label over my image view it doesn't show. How can I make this show

[image]

As seen on the screen shot I can't see my labels 
It appears when I build and run but on the story board the image view hides it this is still a problem.

Comment: Are you adding it programatically or from Storyboard ?

Comment: Are you doing this on the main thread, in two calls that you are sure are called after one another?

Comment: @technerd storyboard

Comment: Please post storyboard image.

Comment: @Jojodmo it shows up when I run but doesn't show up on the storyboard

Comment: @technerd I would but theres no point since you can't see whats under it

Comment: @Jojodmo because I constantly move things around and want to see the items there

Comment: @DanA check my edited answer. let me know if that helps.

Comment: @DanA Alright, you should add that your question is about the actual storyboard, not code. Also, your question will most likely get closed as too broad because you haven't included any images, and haven't given that much information about your actual problem. I don't use storyboards, so I don't know the answer to the question - good luck!

Comment: @DanA check me new edit, I think it answers your question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a story board, if you place the label on top of the image view it will appear that way. Just make sure that you have the proper constraints on both the image view and the label so that they would be on top of each other and it should work. To answer your question, putting a label on top of an image view does not make it disappear.

This would put the label in front of the image view:

[image: This would put the label in front of the imageview]

and this would put it behind the imageview

[image: and this would put it behind the imageview]

Just replace the order from the side menu in storyboard. Put it below the image view and it will be on top

Comment: when I run it appears but on the storyboard it doesn't show

Comment: I edited the answer to show you how to find the label in storyboard.

Comment: I know that but I believe I fixed it one time where I can make the label and other UI items appear over the uiiamge view

Comment: @DanA glad I could help

Comment: which constrains do i need to add?

Answer (score 2):

**The method has been updated since swift 3**

What has worked for me and hopefully for you is using :

```
YourView.bringSubview(toFront: yourelementA)
YourView.bringSubview(toFront: yourelementB)
```

Alternatively you could use the following to send the object that is in the front:

```
YourView.sendSubview(toBack: yourelementC)
```

Comment: This is what I needed to do. Thanks.